# Convert phone number format from (404)-313-2974 to 404-313-2974

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a list of phone numbers entered into Google spreadsheet in this format: `(404) 313-2974`

How can I convert this entered cell into `404-313-2974`?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "(", ""), ") ", "-")
```

[image: 0]

### ___________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "(", ""), ") ", "-"), ))
```

[image: p]

Comment: Please provide an explanation for the syntax of the `SUBSTITUTE` function, so that readers can follow your answer.